# how to get JSON string by using JsonpRequestBuilder

Tags: gwt, jsonp

I am using GWT's JsonpRequestBuilder to issue a cross site REST request whose response is a JSON object.

The callback parameter of requestObject method is a JavaScriptObject. 
but I do not want to implement a JavaScriptObject, but rather to parse the JSON response directly.  Is there anyway I can get the JSON string directly from any method of JavaScriptObject or JsonpRequestBuilder ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the `com.google.gwt.json.JSON` module (seriously, you'd better write `JavaScriptObject`s, this JSON module is a PITA to work with), then you can simply wrap the returned `JavaScriptObject` into a `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`:

```
new JSONObject(myJavaScriptObject)
```

Comment: This works for me, exactly what I want, thank! I wish I could have enough reputation to give you a vote.

Answer (score 1):

Use requestString instead of requestObject. Like this:

```
JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
jsonp.requestString(url,
     new AsyncCallback<String>() { ...
```

This will return a String instead of a JavaScriptObject. You can use then use the JSONParser, like this:

```
JSONObject value = (JSONObject)JSONParser.parseStrict(jsonString);

Person person = new Person();
person.setName(value.get("Name").isString().stringValue());
```

Comment: when i tried AsyncCallback<String> instead of AsyncCallback<JavaScriptObject> , I could not got callback onSuccess or onFailure get called.

Comment: Same, I couldn't get this version to work. In firefox, I get a classcastexception.

Comment: You use `requestString()` when the server returns a string (e.g. `'{"name":"Brad"}'` -- note the apostrophes).  If the server returns a JavaScript object (e.g. a proper JSON value, like `{"name":"Brad"}`), you need to use `requestObject()`.  Using the wrong one will result in ClassCastException.

Answer (score 1):

@Gu
Try to escape quotes in a generated json. For instance in server-side code put

```
    json = json.replace( "\"", "\\\"" )
```

Than wrap resulting string as follows:

```
    String jsonCallback = request.getParameter("jsonpcallback") //or any other name
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    responseBody.append( jsonCallback ).append( "(\"" ).append( json ).append( "\");");
```

This code works for me in client-side:

```
    JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
    jsonp.setCallbackParam("jsonpcallback");
    jsonp.requestString(....);
```

P.S. Sorry. Not enough points just to comment already given answer.